# Corrupted video download

Tags: macos, google-chrome, video, quicktime

I'm using a video downloader on Chrome to download videos. It worked perfectly fine, but recently, when I try to download videos using that extension, the downloaded videos can't be opened in QuickTime Player and it says "The file isn’t compatible with QuickTime Player". I've tried using different extensions but it didn't work, but downloading the video from the source code worked. (I'm using macOS 10.15.4)